# Show Popup with double rendering of View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm working on the Backbone application. I've a Header View, Home View (main content view) and Footer View as child views. All these views load asynchronously.

I need to show the popup every time the Page Loads. The code to show popup is written on Home View which is rendering twice (asynchronously). I cannot stop the double rendering of the Home View. I want to show the popup but the double rendering is causing the popup to disappear.

Please, suggest any alternate solution for this problem.

Comment: Please include a [minimal and complete code snippet](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Answer (score 1):

In view you can create a member variable

```
renderCount=0  

render() {
this.renderCount++;
if(this.renderCount===2){
alert("Rendered Twice");
this.renderCount==0;
}
else{
.........Rest of the render code
}
}
```

This might help your problem
But i will suggest you to debug and find the reason for double rendering